# PowerShell: how to pass , as a string from command line to a powershell sciript

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script Process-OU.ps1 to which I need to pass an argument -OU dc=LON,dc=NOM.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
 .\Process-OU.ps1 -OU "dc=LON,dc=NOM"
```

Comment: or  .\Process-OU.ps1 -OU 'dc=LON,dc=NOM'

Comment: @Kalyan Ghosh - Oh, the -OU was param? Updating my answer for that.

Comment: Or, just for fun, .\Process-OU -OU dc=LON`,dc=NOM